# Offsetting time_t in C++

Tags: c++, linux, time

I am dealing with timestamps generated by a system where the epoch is not the standard UNIX epoch of seconds since midnight of Jan 1, 1970 (it starts somewhere in 1965 instead). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521750/ticks-between-unix-epoch-and-gps-epoch) question is kind of related. So, I have a "fixup" function to deal with this offset:

```
time_t fix_time(uint32_t raw_time)
{
    const int32_t epoch_offset = 157680000; /* offset wrt UNIX epoch */
    time_t fixedTime = static_cast<time_t>(raw_time - epoch_offset);
    return fixedTime;
}
```

and continue using the standard library functions in rest of the code:

```
uint32_t raw_time;
time_t timestamp = fix_timestamp(raw_time);
struct tm timeinfo;
gmtime_r(&timestamp, &timeinfo);
```

It seems to work as intended (held up to a mix of real and synthetic test data, so far). However, is there a better way to deal with this scenario? Are there any subtle ways in which this might break? Additional info if it matters: the timestamps are spread out over 1981 to the current day and the program runs on a Linux machine.

Comment: The `<static_cast<time_t>` is unnecessary; since both `int32_t` and `time_t` are arithmetic types, the conversion is done implicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I generally tend to do that as a note to myself (and others) reading the code that the casting is intentional.

Comment: @BhargavBhat: it can suppress compiler warnings when converting to a type that can't store all the original values, whether due to using less bytes or being signed or unsigned.  More generally, 32 bit values storing date/times in the UNIX Epoch will wrap in 2038 - you've chopped off an extra ~5 years - so should be right until about 2033.

Comment: @TonyD: yup, that seems right. One of the synthetic dates I used was pretty close to UINT32_MAX and I got a date somewhere in November 2033.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time_t` is already a C legacy. For your own time, you should really make a class. The main advantage of such a class is that you can avoid unintended behavior. You define which operators make sense, and `operator^` probably does not. You define which conversions are supported, and that's probably just to `time_t` (if at all - the alternative is a `.getCtime()` method)

Internally, you can use an `unsigned long` which gives you *at least* 68 years extra. The Y2038 problem is because `time_t` is signed, and the UNIX era runs from 1902 to 2038.