# How can I get the GPS week number given a date in C?

Tags: c, date, week-number

I have a date like: `171115 183130` (17-11-15 18:31:30).  I using an API that required me to supply the date based on the week number but since it's for a GPS service it needs to be the week number counting from 1980 (first epoch)

I couldn't find any library in C that takes into consideration leap days/seconds. Any ideas?

For example, week `1873` should be `2015 11 30`.

Comment: See also [Ticks between Unix epoch and GPS epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20521750/2410359) and [What is a GPS epoch?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281223/what-is-a-gps-epoch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `difftime()` no need to assume Jan 1, 1970 epoch.  `difftime()` returns the difference in the 2 time stamps as a number of seconds (`double`).  The return value is independent of the number type and epoch used for `time_t`.

Use `mktime()` to convert YMD to `time_t`.
Open question: timezone not mentioned in OP's post.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

time_t TimeFromYMD(int year, int month, int day) {
  struct tm tm = {0};
  tm.tm_year = year - 1900;
  tm.tm_mon = month - 1;
  tm.tm_mday = day;
  return mktime(&tm);
}

#define SECS_PER_WEEK (60L*60*24*7)

int GPSweek(int year, int month, int day) {
  // See update below
  double diff = difftime(TimeFromYMD(year, month, day), TimeFromYMD(1980, 1, 1));  // See update
  return (int) (diff / SECS_PER_WEEK);
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", GPSweek(2015, 11, 30));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1873
```

---

[edit 2022]

[@Bianca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159790/how-can-i-get-the-gps-week-number-given-a-date-in-c/34160436?noredirect=1#comment130456639_34160436) offered the correction to use Jan 5, 1980 epoch.  Reviewed against [this](https://www.gnsscalendar.com/index.html?year=2022) and determine Jan 6, 1980 is correct which also matches [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521750/ticks-between-unix-epoch-and-gps-epoch).

```
int GPSweek(int year, int month, int day) {
  double diff = difftime(TimeFromYMD(year, month, day), TimeFromYMD(1980, 1, 6));
  return (int) (diff / SECS_PER_WEEK);
}
```

Pedantic: Should a TZ setting include an area that has gained/lost a day due to switching across the International dateline, `mktime()` may be problematic.

Week numbers before Jan 6, 1980 need additional code.

Comment: NOTE - The GPS epoch is 0000 UT (midnight) on January 6, 1980. GPS time is not adjusted and therefore is offset from UTC by an integer number of seconds,

Comment: I order to make it work properly for the current date, inside the GPSweek function, TimeFromYMD(1980, 1, 1) should be changed to -> TimeFromYMD(1980, 1, 5).

Comment: @Bianca Why Jan 5, 1980 and not [Jan 6, 1980](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521750/ticks-between-unix-epoch-and-gps-epoch)?

Comment: I personally don't have a technical explanation right now @chux-ReinstateMonica. I tested the algorithm and compared it to this website https://www.gnsscalendar.com/ and I obtained the correct results only by using Jan 5, 1980 instead of Jan 1, 1980.

Comment: One potential explanation would be: "The starting point (time zero) of GPS time was chosen to be midnight of 5-6 January 1980"

Comment: @Bianca My review concluded Jan 6, 1980.  Please review.  If is fails, please provide sample data as well as value from `difftime(TimeFromYMD(year, month, day), TimeFromYMD(1980, 1, 1))`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, Jan 5 still works  for me instead of 6 Jan. Try for example a date like 2022 09 11 in the main function. With Jan 5 I will get 2227 which is correct, but with Jan 6 I will get 2226.

Comment: @Bianca [as requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159790/how-can-i-get-the-gps-week-number-given-a-date-in-c/34160436?noredirect=1#comment130466332_34160436), what is the return value of `difftime(TimeFromYMD(year, month, day), TimeFromYMD(1980, 1, 1))` in the Jan 6, 1980 case - at least 17 significant places?  e.g. `"%.17g"`. For me, it is `2227.0`.

Answer (score 3):

Since the date shows the day and time separately, you do not need to worry about leap seconds.

Use the C library API to convert from DDMMYY to the number of seconds since the C epoch (1/1/1970), subtract the number of seconds until 1/1/1980 and divide the result by 7*24*3600 to get the number of weeks elapsed from 1/1/1980.